# How to reuse angular javascript unit test modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm new to angular js, trying to write unit test for a function with experiment flags (defined in the build file) on and off respectively, in two different files.

In the first file:

```
describe('MyController', function(){
    var x = var_x;
    beforeEach(...);
    describe('TestFun', function (){
        it('should be **true** when flag is on', function(){
            expect(TestFun(x).toBe(**true**);
        });
    });
});
```

In the second file:

```
describe('MyController', function(){
    var x = var_x;
    beforeEach(...);
    describe('TestFun', function (){
        it('should be **false** when flag is off', function(){
            expect(TestFun(x).toBe(**false**);
        });
    });
});
```

The test can pass, however, there is a lot of duplication in these two files. Is there a fancier way to write these two tests without these duplications? Thanks!

I need two different files because the results of 'TestFun' depends on an experiment flag that can only be turned on in build file, and the flag can not be changed inside javascript file. So I have to write two different files for different test cases.

Comment: Maybe your example is too simple. I wouldn't put those two tests in different files, the 2nd `it()` would be in the first file w/out any duplication. So now that's out of the way, what is it that you're really trying to avoid duplicating?

Comment: The output results of 'TestFun' depends on an experiment flag that can only be turned on in build file, and the flag can not be changed inside javascript file. Thus, I need two different files for different test cases, but I would like to avoid code duplication if possible.

Comment: Ok, I get it now, thanks. I'm not sure how you're getting the value into the test, but perhaps the "parameterized test" approach might be possible. Google "jasmine parameterized tests" and you'll some examples and even a library or two. Another idea would be to have one test template with placeholders for the parameters. Then your build system could generate two test suites from the template.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with template:)